# Override setter doesn't work with update_attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec, overriding, rspec-rails

I'm making an task-manager and have an boolean attribute for 'finished'. I've tried to override the setter to implement an 'finished_at' date when i toggle 'finished' to true.

But i getting some mixed result. It doesn't work in browser but it will work in my rspec test.

Please help me out.

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController 
# ...
def update
  # ..
  if @task.update_attributes(params[:task]) # where params[:task][:finished] is true
# ...
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
#...
  def finished=(f)
   write_attribute :finished, f
   write_attribute :finished_at, f == true ? DateTime.now : nil
  end
end

# and in rspec i have
describe "when marked as finished" do
  before { @task.update_attributes(finished: true) }

  its(:finished_at) { should_not be_nil }
  its(:finished_at) { should > (DateTime.now - 1.minute) }

  describe "and then marked as unfinished" do 
    before { @task.update_attributes(finished: false) }
    its(:finished_at) { should be_nil }
  end
end
```

in browser it executes "UPDATE "tasks" SET "finished" = 't', "updated_at" = '2012-10-02 18:55:07.220361' WHERE "tasks"."id" = 17"

and in rails console i got the same with update_attributes.

But in rspec with update_attributes i get "UPDATE "tasks" SET "finished" = 't', "finished_at" = '2012-10-02 18:36:47.725813', "updated_at" = '2012-10-02 18:36:51.607143' WHERE "tasks"."id" = 1"

So I use the same method but it's only working in rspec for some reson...

---

using latest rails and latest spec (not any rc or beta).

### Solution

Not mush i did need to edit. Thanks @Frederick Cheung for the hint.
I did notice i did like "self[:attr]" more than "write_attribute". Looks better imo.

```
def finished=(value)
  self[:finished] = value
  self[:finished_at] = (self.finished? ? Time.now.utc : nil)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setter is passed the values as they are passed to `update_attributes`. In particular when this is triggered by a form submission (and assuming you are using the regular rails form helpers) `f` will actually be "0" or "1", so the comparison with `true` will always be false.

The easiest thing would be to check the value of `finished?` after the first call to `write_attribute`, so that rails can convert the submitted value to true/false. It's also unrubyish to do `== true` - this will break if the thing you are testing returns a truthy value rather than actually true (for example =~ on strings returns an integer when there is a match)

Comment: Do you know why it doesn't fail under my rspec tests? Or am I making some wrong there?

Comment: Because in your test you're passing through true/false but in the controller "0"/"1" is being passed

Comment: So I have to make an test for this in spec-file for the web-page to? Or do you know any fail-safe options to test this in the model spec?

Atleast it's working now, but a bit scared to be in the position where my web-apps grow and all are looking god in rspec-test, but it is not becouse I have written the wrong test.

Comment: this is why detailed model level specs are typically accompanied by higher level integration specs that test the whole stack.

Answer (score 1):

You could use ActiveRecord Dirty Tracking to be notified of this change.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_save :toggle_finished_at

  def toggle_finished_at
    if finished_changed?
      before = changes['finished'][0]
      after = changes['finished'][1]
      # transition from finished => not-finished
      if before == true && after == false
        self.finished_at = nil
      end
      # transition from not finished => finished
      if before == false && after == true
        self.finished_at = Time.now.utc
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Yes this works, besides the typo. _self.finished_at = Time.now.utc_ shod be in the last if-block. But it's still not what i want. I'm still in learning phase and I think this code is a bit hard to read. I had to read it twice to know what it does.

Answer (score 0):

This is a use case for a state machine. You call a `:finish!` event (a method) which is configured to change the state and to do whatever else needed.

https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine/

Comment: Did not really understand that. But looks interesting so have to read more on that. Thanks for help anyway.